# I am using MQTTClient In an ios App where i would like to save the data of an user when it subscribes to the topic

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile, mqtt

I have searched on google about this but aparently no one has tried this or its not the best practice.

I get the MQTT client object and am able to communicate , problem is arising when i want to save their chat and bothe clients so as when the either of them comes online or goes offline the other could get a notification.

a Psuedo code or just a flow directing this approach would be enough as i am unable to visualise the flow of the mentioned process.

Please guide me to a tutorial or just help me understand the flow of things here.

This is a demo i am preparing as a a part of studying MQTT systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is achievable using MQTT but you will need to make use of two features.

First, you must make sure your clients connect using non-clean sessions (and make sure they always connect using the same client name which needs to be unique to them). This will ensure that the client's state is saved on the MQTT broker; in other words, the subscription will only need to be added the first time the clients connect.

Second, you will need to make use of QoS 1 subscriptions and QoS 1 publishing. Publishing at QoS 1 will guarantee that the message has been successfully received by the MQTT broker and delivered to all destinations. A QoS 1 subscription will guarantee that the message will be delivered to the client regardless of if its online or not at the time it was published (assuming it had requested a non-clean session if its currently offline).

Additionally, I would suggest using QoS 0 for sending notifications for when a client comes "online" (but all other "chat" messages can and should be sent/received at QoS 1).

Comment: Thank you for the advice. 
It helped me solve the predicament. Much appreciated.

Comment: will you be also able to tell me about the limitations on the contents that i can send via MQTT message?

Comment: The payload of an MQTT message can be viewed as a byte array. This gives you enough flexibility to transport any content assuming that proper transformation is done at the software level.